# Google Cloud - limit create only 12 VM Instances

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I create VM Instances. Create Vm's with Instance Group.
When i choose to create more than 12 VM Instances or try add more vm instances to 12 that exist - they not create more than 12 and not receive any error.

How can i create more than 12 VM Instances ?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably hitting a CPU quota limit for Compute Engine.

Please check your quota page and operations page for error details.

In the quota page there is the link to request a quota increase.

Sincerely,
Paolo